# Azure storage - custom domains per container

Tags: azure, subdomain, azure-storage

Is there any way to assign custom domains to an azure container, but not to the whole account?

For instance, I have two containers: */images* and */downloads*

I want to put a custom domain for each one like:

- images.mydomain.com -> blob.core.windows.net/images
- downloads.mydomain.com ->  blob.core.windows.net/downloads

I searched but did not find any results about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation her: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/storage/custom-dns-storage/, while it is possible to map a custom domain to a storage account, I don't think it is possible to map a custom domain to a blob container.

What you could do is have a sub domain like assets.yourdomain.com and map it to a storage account and then have two blob containers called "images" and "downloads" in there so that the blob containers work like a virtual directory.

Comment: What a shame... I wanted many custom domains to increase download parallelism in my site.Thanks!

Comment: If you only have two, you could map an Azure CDN address to the custom domain.  This would net you the benefit of edge caching and increase download parallelism.  My personal experience has been that certain high volume/repeat images are best cached on the client or memory for optimal speed...rather than worrying about a couple extra threads.  Furthermore, having a service that can return combined sprites with dynamic json/css so everything is handled in 2 requests which works great for many small files requested at once.